# How to organize logging mySql queries in C #

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

In ADO.net have the opportunity:

```
DbInterception.Add (new LogFormatter());
```

Is there any an analogue for mySql without ADO

Can I use for this BaseCommandInterceptor, if yes that as?

Desirably example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this on
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing.html